# ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size IPython

Tags: ipython

I am having this error with my IPython version on Redhat.

```
$ ipython --version

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in module

    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 24, in <module>

   from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 28, in module

    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 121, in module

    from IPython.utils.terminal import get_terminal_size
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/terminal.py", line 27, in module

    import backports.shutil_get_terminal_size
**ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size**
```

Could you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: Similar quesiton and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232446/ipython-console-cant-locate-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size-and-wont-load

Comment: I tried to uninstall and re install but still with the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same question as yours. I solve it by using `pip install -U ipython` to update IPython and it workes. Hope it helps!

Comment: For me, I needed to upgrade pip and specially setuptools with `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` and reinstall (remove and install again) ipython.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232446/ipython-console-cant-locate-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size-and-wont-load), try:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install backports.shutil_get_terminal_size
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use conda, try below.

`pip install https://github.com/chrippa/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size/archive/159e269450dbf37c3a837f6ea7e628d59acbb96a.zip`

Answer (score 1):

None of the uninstalling/reinstalling stuff worked for me. What eventually worked for me was suggested by @ternus in a comment above: open up (on linux) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/terminal.py and change the line

from backports.shutil_get_terminal_size import get_terminal_size as _get_terminal_size
to

from shutil_backports import get_terminal_size as _get_terminal_size

Reference: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9656
Author: https://github.com/ihincks

Answer (score 0):

I follow this post 
[IPython console can't locate "backports.shutil_get_terminal_size" and won't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232446/ipython-console-cant-locate-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size-and-wont-load)

to change /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/terminal.py and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked (on Debian):

```
apt-get install python-ipython
```