# When can import find a module when nothing else can?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In short, how can this happen?

```
cternus@astarael:~⟫ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 14:05:02)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import backports
>>> import imp
>>> imp.find_module('backports')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named backports
```

The [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module claims to be "an interface to the mechanisms used to implement the import statement." If this is so, **why can the `import` statement find `backports`, but `imp.find_module()` can't?**

For some background: [backports](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports/1.0) claims to be a "namespace package," not a package in its own right; other modules, such as `backports.shutil_get_terminal_size`, are situated in this namespace. This formed the basis of [an ultimately-rejected PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/). I'm asking this question because I'm having a variant of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232446/ipython-console-cant-locate-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size-and-wont-load) and am trying to track down the cause.

For more weirdness:

```
>>> backports.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
>>> dir(backports)
['__doc__', '__name__', '__path__']
>>> backports.__path__
['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/backports']
>>> import os; os.path.exists(backports.__path__[0])
False
```

(And no, I have no files or directories named `backports` or `backports.py` anywhere on my system.)

**Edited to clarify**: I am aware that this probably represents a strange configuration state of my system. My question is not "how can I fix this" but "how is it possible?"

Comment: Probably should be "What's so special about my Python environment?", because I get `backports.__file__ == '.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/__init__.pyc'` well enough. How did you install backports?

Comment: out of curiosity, before doing `import backports` try checking `"backports" in sys.modules` and if it is already loaded try importing after `del sys.modules["backports"]`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen `'backports': <module 'backports' (built-in)>` Huuuuuhhhh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module can be brought by `python-configparser` APT package.

> how is it possible?

This is possible because `python-configparser` uses **path configuration file** (`.pth` file):

```
root@ubuntu18.10:/# dpkg -L python-configparser | head | tail -n 1
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configparser-3.5.0b2-nspkg.pth
```

This file is automatically picked up by python's **site** module on interpreter startup because it is located in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` and has `.pth` extension. As [docs say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html):

> A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form name.pth and exists in one of the four directories mentioned above...
>   Lines starting with import (followed by space or tab) are executed.

The file `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configparser-3.5.0b2-nspkg.pth` contains the following:

```
import sys, types, os;has_mfs = sys.version_info > (3, 5);p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('backports',));importlib = has_mfs and __import__('importlib.util');has_mfs and __import__('importlib.machinery');m = has_mfs and sys.modules.setdefault('backports', importlib.util.module_from_spec(importlib.machinery.PathFinder.find_spec('backports', [os.path.dirname(p)])));m = m or sys.modules.setdefault('backports', types.ModuleType('backports'));mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]);(p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
```

So, this code is auto-executed on python startup. Slightly beautified, it looks like this:

```
import sys, types, os

has_mfs = sys.version_info > (3, 5)

p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('backports',))
importlib = has_mfs and __import__('importlib.util')
has_mfs and __import__('importlib.machinery')

m = has_mfs and sys.modules.setdefault('backports', importlib.util.module_from_spec(importlib.machinery.PathFinder.find_spec('backports', [os.path.dirname(p)])))

m = m or sys.modules.setdefault('backports', types.ModuleType('backports'))

mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[])

(p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
```

What it does (at least on python 2) is: it **manually** creates a module object by invoking `types.ModuleType` constructor (that's why it looks like `<module 'backports' (built-in)>`) and puts it to `sys.modules` with `sys.modules.setdefault('backports', types.ModuleType('backports'))`. After it was added to `sys.modules`, `import backports` will just return that object.

`__path__` gives a hint

```
root@ubuntu18.10:/# python -c 'import backports; print backports.__path__'
['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports']
root@ubuntu18.10:/# dpkg -S /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports
python-configparser: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports
```

> I have no files or directories named backports

On Ubuntu, there *is* `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports` brought by this package as shown above, so I'm not sure why you don't have it. Maybe it's another package behaving similarly/variant of it for MacOS is different/you just deleted that dir while debugging the issue?